# ViewController not displaying even though segue has been triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I have a `TableViewController` and I would like to trigger a segue within its navigation bar. I created the segue in the storyboard to my new `ViewController`. However if I click the bar button item, the view does not appear.

Instead the bar button item becomes inactive (greyed out) and the app freezes. There is no error message and the app does also not crash. The `prepareForSegue` method in my `TableViewController` also gets called

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

   print("prepare for segue called")
   print("destination view controller = \(segue.destinationViewController.description)")

}
```

I did the following things:

1. created a custom view Controller class for the second screen (in my storyboard and as a .swift file). I assigned the respective `ViewController` in the storyboard to my custom view controller in the Identity inspector
2. created an `IBAction` for a click event on the button and triggered
   the segue programatically. The result remains the same.
   `prepareForSegue` is called. The `destionationViewController` is correct
   but does not show up. I removed this `IBAction` afterwards.

My destination view controller looks like this

```
class EnterUserDataViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("EnterUserDataViewController viewDidLoad called")
    }

}
```

`viewDidLoad` never gets called even though the right segue has been triggered.

Can someone please give me a hint on why this happens?

[image: My outline. I'm trying to create a segue from the ExtraViewController to the EnterUserDataViewController]

[image: Segue]

Comment: Do your screenshots match your actual code still? You say you're manually triggering the segue using an action outlet, but your screens show that the tab bar button is directly triggering the segue.

Comment: No I thought that I could have done something wrong. Then I tried to trigger the segue programatically. So I created an IBAction and called performSegueWithIdentifier. However this did not help. So I deleted this IBAction and used a normal "drag and drop" segue. To anser your question: Yes.

Comment: Any update on this issue? Have you been able to solve it? @slashburn

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I resolved this issue. I think the problem was that the segue was triggered multiple times. If the app freezes this usually happens if you try to access something that doesn't exist any more. Today, I don't use storyboards any more and do everything programatically

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't happen to have a rogue breakpoint set somewhere would you?

If I put a breakpoint somewhere in the view loading cycle it recreates the exact symptoms you are describing.